# What is the difference between two highlighted functions?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

[image]

There is no syntactical difference so it is a bit confusing, please check this documentation - [Element](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/api#id_59154)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was just a mistake in the documentation, listing the same method twice. I have filed a documentation bug to get that corrected.